# Problem with see-through windows in XP

Tags: windows-xp, gui

After my PC has been on for a bit (15mins?) some of my windows start displaying see-through properties and other bizarre characteristics (like being able to draw on each other with by dragging the windows over other windows).

Now, this PC is a Core2Quad, 4GB system with Windows XP SP3 32bit. The graphics are 128MB PCI NVidia.

Below you can see a screenshot of a Ubuntu session in Virtualbox showcasing this:

[image: wild windows]

However, any and every window can do this. Chrome, Firefox, OpenOffice, anything that is a window occasionally pops-up see-through. Most the time it happens when I minimize a window and then pull it back up later. So perhaps some re-draw based on the memory isn't happening.

Comment: Could be a number of things.  Problems with the video memory, RAM starvation.  It does look like you've got a lot of programs open there.  How much RAM is installed?

Comment: Also, how come you are discussing Ubuntu and Windows XP in the same question?

Comment: To clarify: this happens to windows inside your VirtualBox Ubuntu VM, but it **also** happens to windows on your host Windows XP?

Comment: @Robert A VM allows you to run client OS inside a host OS. Also, my question states that I have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Was that a response to Robert Harvey's comment?

Comment: @boot13 This happens in any window in XP - so that means that the ubuntu VM running in XP is also affected by it since it is inside a window in XP.

Comment: I have never seen or even heard of this behavior before... I'm interested in seeing what theories other people come up with.  All I can guess is going to go along with the answer already posted: update your drivers and make sure you're not overheating.

Comment: Is the system overclocked at all?

Comment: This is interesting.  I suspect it's probably bad video RAM (or it could just be getting too hot)...trying swapping the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as out of date display drivers.  It definitely seems like a display issue to me.  Since you said it starts happening after the machine has been powered on for a while, it could be heat-related as well.  Make sure the display card's fan is operating and that it isn't getting too hot.  You can install freeware hardware monitoring software like [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to help you get a handle on that.

Comment: I updated the drivers just a bit ago - and this also occurs when I use other video cards (like my 512MB PCIe). I also doubt this has anything to do with heat since I'm using an Antec 900 case with 4x 120mm and 1x 200mm fans on it. Sandra reports CPU @ 30C and mobo @ 38C.

Comment: @Xeoncross: What about the GPU: does it have a fan?  What temperature is reported for the GPU?

Comment: I'm not showing anything for the GPU and the system is not OC'ed

Comment: I changed to a new ati Video card (instead of the other two nvidia) and I haven't had the problem anymore.